# INSERTED magic table in case of in place Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I saw a nice post in which the author has proven that if you are updating a column of a table without any indexes defined, an "in place update" will occur and not traditional delete\insert.

Considering this I run a small test where I have created an `Update` trigger on table and try to access the `INSERTED` magic table and here is the catch.

I am able to access the `INSERTED` magic table, can someone explain me if in place update is not using traditional Delete\Insert? How come one can access the magic tables?

These are my SQL statement to prove this thing.

Main table :

```
CREATE TABLE TestingUpdate1 (
  ID INT IDENTITY,
  SomeString CHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO TestingUpdate1 (SomeString)
VALUES
('One'),('Two'),('Three'),('Four'),('Five'),('Six'),('Seven'),('Eight'),('Nine')

CHECKPOINT -- truncate the log, DB is in simple recovery.

UPDATE TestingUpdate1
SET SomeString = 'NotFour'
WHERE ID = 4 -- one row

SELECT Operation, Context, AllocUnitName, [Transaction Name], Description FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) AS TranLog
```

Second table :

```
CREATE TABLE TestingUpdate4 (
  ID INT IDENTITY,
  SomeString CHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO TestingUpdate4 (SomeString)
VALUES
('One'),('Two'),('Three'),('Four'),('Five'),('Six'),('Seven'),('Eight'),('Nine')
```

Trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER ViewCustomerTrigger ON TestingUpdate1
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE TestingUpdate4 
SET SomeString = i.SomeString
FROM INSERTED i
END
GO

select * from TestingUpdate4
select * from TestingUpdate1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `Inserted` (and `Deleted`) system pseudo table are **always** available in your trigger - no matter **how** the update really happens...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables in an update trigger always show the **logical** before and after versions of the updated rows.

Whether that is **physically** implemented as an in place update or as an insert/delete is execution plan dependant and irrelevant to the contents of these tables.

Comment: Thanks Smith for your reply.Can you please give some example to understand the difference?

Comment: @user2140234 - Some example of what? The question sounds like you understand the difference between in place updates and insert/deletes and the point of my answer is that there is **no** difference between the two when it comes to the contents of the pseudo tables.

Comment: @user2140234 - Still not sure exactly what example you were hoing for. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14082375/73226)  shows a case where 9 update operations get physically implemented as  1 delete, 8 in place updates, and an insert. The `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables will still both have 9 rows though. The contents are independent of the physical implementation.