# SQL How UPDATE command works

Tags: sql, sql-update

How does the UPDATE command in SQL work?
I have a table with three columns a,b,c where a is the primary key.
the values in the table are (1,2,3),(2,4,5).
Suppose i want to update this tuple and set the value of column c to 4 where values of a is 1.
Is the tuple (1,2,3) deleted and then a new tuple is inserted ?
Or the values 1,2 are kept constant 3 is deleted and 4 is inserted ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? The actual implementation on _how_ this is implemented technically behind the scenes is _highly_ DBMS dependent (and sometimes even dependent on the actual statement the tables involved and any possible index)

Comment: For SQL Server updates can be in place, or delete/insert or a hybrid of the  two.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14082375/73226

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify which databases are of particular interest, I'm going to pick MySQL. (But it's not too far-fetched to say most other relational databases have similar implementation.)

In a nutshell, MySQL `UPDATE` supports both single-table syntax and multiple-table syntax. In both cases, the tuples are not deleted, then re-inserted. The edits happened directly to the columns specify by the `SET` clause.

Right at the top of the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html), it says that

> For the single-table syntax, the UPDATE statement updates columns of existing rows in the named table with new values.

then

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times.

There is no mentions of a `DELETE THEN RE-INSERT` operation. In your case, yes, values 1 and 2 are kept constant, while 3 is replaced by 4.

Answer (score 0):

This should edit your table entry not adding the new tuple to your table

```
UPDATE tableName
SET c='4'
WHERE a='1'
```

Comment: The update statement overwrites only the changed data. The database server may have to physically move your data record to a new page, but this is transparent to you. Data in 1+2 are kept constant.

Comment: yes the updated value only change other values are not affected.

Comment: you can modify data in individual rows, sets of rows, or all rows in a table. An UPDATE statement must always include a SET clause, which identifies the columns to be updated. In addition, the statement can include a WHERE clause, which determines what rows to modify, or a FROM clause, which identifies tables or views that provide values for the expressions defined in the SET clause.

Comment: how is it changed? Is it just overwritten or taken to a temporary place for modifying it?

Comment: i think it is overwrite the value in the particular column

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `UPDATE` first locates all matching rows (which you are calling tuples), then modifies them. It does not delete or add any rows.

**However**, <strike>an `UPDATE` statement will fire both `DELETE` and `INSERT` triggers, if any are defined. It therefore does appear to be a delete and an insert, from a certain point of view.</strike>

**EDIT:** What I meant to say was, when an `UPDATE` trigger fires, the data before the `UPDATE` are available in the `DELETED` pseudotable, while the data after the `UPDATE` appear in the `INSERTED` pseudotable.  It is in this sense only that an `UPDATE` looks a little like a delete plus an insert. I apologize for my misstatement above.

Comment: That was an idiotic thing for me to say. Editing with what I really meant.

Answer (score -1):

Update table_name
set c='4'
where a='1';

This would work fine without any issues and it would not delete or add a new tuple to your table.

Comment: Linking to documentation in order to explain your answer and teach them how to solve the problem rather than simply providing the answers would be better. Thanks for giving an answer though!